# How to check if a page your are on has a success massage on it

Tags: template, session, forms

I need to add a a piece of javascript (a quantast tracking pixel) to the `/contacts/index/` page when the user successfully sends a message by completing the contact us form.

Similarrly I need to add another piece of JavaScript code to the `/customer/account/index` when the user create a customer account, and again for another page where the user books an appointment.

Is there away I could check from a Magento Template file if the user is is on a page which has a success message?

Answer (score 4):

The success messages (and all other types of messages) are added by default inside an `ul` element with the class 'messages'.
You can check via JS if such an element exists in the DOM:

```
var messageLength = $$('ul.messages').length;
if (messageLength > 0) {
    //there are messages
} else {
    //there are no messages
}
```

if you want to check only for success messages change the dom selector above from `ul.messages` to `ul.messages li.success-msg`.
Each message type is shown in a seperate `li` element that has a class depending on the message type. `success-msg` is for success messages.

**[EDIT]**
I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think you can get the messages stored in the session by using `$messages = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(false)`. This should give you back an instance if `Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection` without removing them from the session. you can later get the success messages from the variable above like this `$success = $messages->getItemsByType('success')`.

But you have to call this code before the messages are displayed in the page, because when they are displayed they are removed from the session.

Comment: I thought of this approach but was trying to load my JS when the DOM loaded not after it loaded.  Perhaps it is ok to add it after the DOM loads but my concern was that as the the JS I'm trying to add is a tracking pixel for quantast analytics it should be loaded with the DOM on to be effective.

Comment: @CreedBratton. See my edit to the answer. Maybe it helps.

Comment: thanks.  With your code I was able to check if the message was a success or error message. Brilliant  :)

Comment: in practice this did not work :(, the `Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection` gets the last message & does distinguish if it is active or not so if the user navigates back to the homepage they get the same data. What does the `false` param mean in `getMessages(false)` mean?

Comment: also `$success = $messages->getItemsByType('success')` just returned an empty array.  Perhaps I'm calling the code too late?  but it works with `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(false)->getLastAddedMessage()->getType();`

Comment: @CreedBratton the parameter for `getMessages` means `$clear`. You don't want to clear them from the session. Also the messages are separated by session type. There are more than one session type `customer/session` is one, `core/session` is an other. There is also `checkout/session` and there might be others. Maybe you need to check all of them for success messages.